# Using Meiryo font causes input field to stretch

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am using a famous japanese font called "Meiryo" for on a japanese website. However, the usage of this font causes all my input fields to stretch. It is a very strange bug, if i replace the font by anything else, all my input fields get back to normal.

Anybody can explain me why this bug occurs please?

Tested on all major browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not a bug. An `<input type=text>` element has its visible size set by the `size` attribute (defaulted to 20), which sets the width in “characters”. This means “average width” characters according to HTML 4, whereas HTML5 drafts say that “the user agent should ensure that at least that many characters are visible”. The reality varies across browsers. In any case, the visible width of the element should depend and actually depends on the properties of the font – on the widths of glyphs in it.

The following simple test (which assumes some common default font to be used for `input`) illustrates this:

```
<input value="Hello world"><br>
<input value="Hello world" style="font-family: Meiryo">
```

The latter element is considerably wider, and by looking at the appearance of the initial text, set you can see the reason to that: in Meiryo, characters (glyphs) are generally wider than in fonts commonly used as default `input` fonts.

The conclusions depend on the page design and layout. In flexible design, the details of layout adapt to the requirements of data and fonts, rather than the other way around. If the design is more rigid, you might consider setting an upper limit on the width in CSS, using pixels if you really must, e.g. `max-width: 200px`.

Answer (score 0):

it's font issue

use CSS **width** and **height** property to solve the problem